# Host replied with server error: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.UUID

Tags: solr, cassandra, datastax

I am using Datastax solution (DSE).

Here is Cassandra model:

```
CREATE TABLE mykeyspace.mytable (
uid uuid,
date_tsp timestamp,
solr_query text,
text_txt text,
PRIMARY KEY (uid, date_tsp)
)
```

my solr schema.xml:

```
<schema name="mytable" version="1.5">
 <types>
  <fieldType name="uuid" class="solr.UUIDField"/>
  <fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField"/>
  <fieldType name="date" class="solr.TrieDateField"/>
 </types>

 <fields>
  <field name="uid"  type="uuid" indexed="true"  stored="true" docValues="true"/>
  <field name="date_tsp"  type="date" indexed="true"  stored="true" docValues="true"/>
  <field name="text_txt"  type="text" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
 </fields>

 <defaultSearchField>text_txt</defaultSearchField>
 <uniqueKey>(uid, date_tsp)</uniqueKey>
</schema>
```

Data:

```
insert into mytable (uid, date_tsp, text_txt)
values (75803436-289c-4131-a766-6ba4b7151983, dateof(now()), 'text 1');

insert into mytable (uid, date_tsp, text_txt)
values (75803436-289c-4131-a766-6ba4b7151983, dateof(now()), 'text 2');

insert into mytable (uid, date_tsp, text_txt)
values (75803436-289c-4131-a766-6ba4b7151983, dateof(now()), 'text 3');

insert into mytable (uid, date_tsp, text_txt)
values (uuid(), dateof(now()), 'text 11');
```

Working Cassandra queries (run from Datastax DevCenter):

```
SELECT * FROM text_heard WHERE solr_query='*1*';

SELECT uid, date_tsp, text_txt FROM text_heard 
WHERE uid = 75803436-289c-4131-a766-6ba4b7151983;

SELECT date_tsp, text_txt FROM text_heard 
WHERE uid = 75803436-289c-4131-a766-6ba4b7151983 
AND solr_query = 'text_txt:*1*';
```

but query (with **uid** in SELECT clause):

```
SELECT uid, date_tsp, text_txt FROM text_heard 
WHERE uid = 75803436-289c-4131-a766-6ba4b7151983 
AND solr_query = 'text_txt:*1*';
```

produces an error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.UUID
at org.apache.cassandra.serializers.UUIDSerializer.serialize(UUIDSerializer.java:26) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.8.621.jar:2.1.8.621]
at org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.AbstractType.decompose(AbstractType.java:73) ~[cassandra-all-2.1.8.621.jar:2.1.8.621]
at com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.cql.SinglePassRowResponseHandler.buildCassandraRows(SinglePassRowResponseHandler.java:140) ~[dse-4.7.2.jar:4.7.2]
at com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.cql.SinglePassRowResponseHandler.handle(SinglePassRowResponseHandler.java:49) ~[dse-4.7.2.jar:4.7.2]
at com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.cql.CqlSolrQueryExecutor.handleSolrResponse(CqlSolrQueryExecutor.java:370) [dse-4.7.2.jar:4.7.2]
at com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.cql.CqlSolrQueryExecutor.execute(CqlSolrQueryExecutor.java:134) [dse-4.7.2.jar:4.7.2]
at com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.cql3.SolrOperationFactory$SolrStatementExecution.execute(SolrOperationFactory.java:71) [dse-4.7.2.jar:4.7.2]
at com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.cql3.DseQueryHandler$Operation.executeWithTiming(DseQueryHandler.java:223) [dse-4.7.2.jar:4.7.2]
at com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.cql3.DseQueryHandler$Operation.executeWithAuditLogging(DseQueryHandler.java:259) [dse-4.7.2.jar:4.7.2]
at com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.cql3.DseQueryHandler.process(DseQueryHandler.java:94) [dse-4.7.2.jar:4.7.2]
at org.apache.cassandra.transport.messages.QueryMessage.execute(QueryMessage.java:119) [cassandra-all-2.1.8.621.jar:2.1.8.621]
at org.apache.cassandra.transport.Message$Dispatcher.channelRead0(Message.java:439) [cassandra-all-2.1.8.621.jar:2.1.8.621]
at org.apache.cassandra.transport.Message$Dispatcher.channelRead0(Message.java:335) [cassandra-all-2.1.8.621.jar:2.1.8.621]
at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105) [netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:333) [netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.access$700(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:32) [netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$8.run(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:324) [netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [na:1.7.0_71]
at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.AbstractTracingAwareExecutorService$FutureTask.run(AbstractTracingAwareExecutorService.java:164) [cassandra-all-2.1.8.621.jar:2.1.8.621]
at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.SEPWorker.run(SEPWorker.java:105) [cassandra-all-2.1.8.621.jar:2.1.8.621]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_71]
```

Is it something in my settings or is it a bug?

Comment: Which version of Cassandra and DevCenter are you running?  I tried your examples with Cassandra 2.0.16 and DevCenter 1.4.0, but I can't seem to reproduce your error.

Comment: Do you have a string that was accidentally inserted in the UUID column?

Comment: @Aaron I am running it on Datastax sandbox 2.1, DevCenter 1.4.1, Cassandra 2.1.8, Solr 4.3.0. Same error appears when I run same query from Java Spring application.

Comment: @Nathan UUID is inserted into uid column. I can get it with mentioned "Working" queries.

Comment: Just wondering, but does that query work for you from within cqlsh?

Comment: DSE 4.7.x ships with Solr 4.10 not 4.3.0. This seems strange though, can you reproduce on a fresh table?

Comment: @Aaron No, it doesn't, same issue, DevCenter 1.4.0 as well.

Comment: @phact Datastax sandbox 2.1 contains DSE 4.7.2. According to /home/datastax/dse/nodes/node1/resources/solr/CHANGES.txt Solr version is 4.3.0, hovever in /home/datastax/dse/nodes/node1/clients I found solr-solrj-4.10.3.0.101.jar. What do you mean by "fresh table". I created table, insert couple of rows, run solr integration with mentioned schema, reindexing, run problematic query from application, DevCenter and cqlsh.

Comment: If you create a new table (different name) can you reproduce this?

Comment: @phact Yes. I created new keyspace, new table, insert two rows, run solr integration - same behaviour.

Comment: Okay can you include the rows you inserted so we can reproduce.

Comment: @phact see Data section.

Comment: This is a bug which will be solved in 4.7.4. As a workaround, move the uid condition inside the solr_query clause: the query will be less efficient but should work at that point.

Comment: @sbtourist Thanks. Since I knew uid before I run query I can select data without uid and enhance returned objects with uid later on. This is my workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a known issue with reading UUID types that's been fixed in the following DSE releases: 4.7.4, 4.8.0

> Single pass queries do not work with UUID, TimeUUID, Inet, Decimal, and Varint types. (DSP-6443)

See the following [DSE4.8 release notes](http://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.8/datastax_enterprise/RNdse.html)